# Ошибка при сериализации сложной модели DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Стоит задача создания JSON файла с полным списком заказа в интернет магазине.
Ожидаемый результат:

```
[
    {
        "delivery": {
            "delivery_time": "2016-07-06T14:14:26Z",
            "delivery_adress": "Тестовый адрес тоставки",
            "phone": "12345678"
        },
        'products': [
            {"product": 1,"count": "2"},
            {"product": 2,"count": "1"},
            {"product": 3,"count": "4"},
            ...
         ],  
        "paymentMethod": {
            "id": 2
        },
        "summ": "1900",
        "success": false
    }
]
```

Для этого есть несколько сериализаторов, на данный момент сериализатор delivery и paymentMethod отрабатывают корректно, не получается добавить products.

```
class OrderProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        fields = ('product','count') 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return OrderProduct.objects.create(**validated_data) 

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    delivery = DeliverySerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    orderProduct_set=OrderProductSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields =('delivery','paymentMethod','summ','success','orderProduct_set'),
```

Ошибка которую получаю

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `orderProduct_set` on serializer `OrderSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Order` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Order' object has no attribute 'orderProduct_set'.
```

Модели

```
class Order (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    summ =models.CharField(max_length=15,default='0')
    delivery = models.ForeignKey('Delivery')
    success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paymentMethod = models.ForeignKey('Payments')
    def __int__(self):
        return self.id

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey('Order')
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='0')
    product = models.ForeignKey('product.Product')
    count = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='0')
    def __int__(self):
            return self.id
```

Comment: orderproduct_set наверно в нижнем регистре надо, регистр имеет значение

Comment: Да, верно, смена регистра промогла

Answer (score 1):

По совету @feroxtl помогла смена регистра в

```
orderProduct_set=OrderProductSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields =('delivery','paymentMethod','summ','success','orderProduct_set'),
```

Правильный вариант

```
orderproduct_set=OrderProductSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields =('delivery','paymentMethod','summ','success','orderproduct_set'),
```